# Strategy to perform many Geocode requests

Tags: ios, swift, geocoding

I have an app that needs to convert many addresses to CLPlacemark to get the latitude/longitude.
In the Apple documentation it's explained that we should not perform many GeoCode request, Geocoding requests are rate limited.

In my App, to perform the Geocoding I just request one Address and when I get the answer I will request the next one, until I have received the lat/long for all my addresses.

I will put this code in a dedicated thread to not block the user. It seems to work but is it a good strategy? How can I be sure Apple will not blacklist my App or return error for my requests.

```
   geoCodingFor(myAddress, index: 0) 

private func geoCodingFor(contacts:[String], index:Int) {
    if index < contacts.count {
        let address = contacts[index]
        CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in
            if let theError = error  {
                print("\(#function) geocode has failed for address \(address) with error \(theError .localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                if let thePlacemark = placemarks {
                    if thePlacemark.count > 0 {
                        print("=> Found placemark for address \(address)")
                    } else {
                        print("No placemark for address \(address)")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("\(#function) Warning geocode has no results for address \(address)")
                }
            }
            if index < contacts.count {
                self.geoCodingFor(contacts, index: index + 1)
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("\(#function) ================> Geocoding is completed")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short:** Maybe just try `sleep(2)` before each geocoding request.

**Long:** While one cannot be certain if Apple would 'blacklist' their app. I am not sure 'blacklisting' app for geocoding a lot exists.

I myself have tried a similar strategy to yours. Only used outer variable `queue` and perform `queue.popLast()`. Doing this gave me like a 100 results and then I started getting an error for the rest of the addresses.

I have added a `sleep(2)` before each geocoding request and I managed to extract more than 4000 geocodings with no blocking.

The downside is - it takes more time. Depending on how many addresses you are planning to geocode this might be useful.

Also please note that I never tried `sleep(1)`, which could also work to some extent.

According to Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/) 'maximum rate' is not specified and they recommend that

> you should not send more than one geocoding request per minute

I hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Based on your experience what I will try is to serialize my requests (as I currently do) but in case of errors then I will add a sleep() before to request the failed request and followings. I cannot add a sleep between each request because it will take too much time for the user. Maybe another option could be to use several geocoding providers in parallel... I think the max number of geocoding requests I need is less than 500.