# API call only returns response once in loop

Tags: ios, swift, api, core-location

I am using a loop and making making API calls to CLGeocoder. The API gets called the correct amount of times, but the completionHandler is only returned once, for the first API call, then it doesn't return anything for the rest of the calls.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                    {                            
                        for shop in self.shopsList {
                            let shopAddress = shop.address
                            self.geocoder.geocodeAddressString(shopAddress, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
                                if let error = error {
                                    print(error)
                                    return
                                }
                                if let placemarks = placemarks where placemarks.count > 0 {
                                    if let location = placemarks.first?.location {
                                        print("The longitude: \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
                                        print("The latitude: \(location.coordinate.latitude)")
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        }

                        self.spinner.dismiss()
                        self.categoryTableView.dataSource = self
                        self.categoryTableView.delegate = self
                        self.categoryTableView.reloadData()
                }
```

The rest of the calls don't return anything at all, don't even enter any of the if statements. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

I have tried adding `sleep(2)` at the end of the for loop, but it still only returns once

Answer (score 1):

You aren't allowed to submit multiple geocoding requests in a row like that. All but the first are likely being rejected.

To quote the docs on `CLGeocoder`:

> Applications should be conscious of how they use geocoding. Geocoding
>   requests are rate-limited for each app, so making too many requests in
>   a short period of time may cause some of the requests to fail. (When
>   the maximum rate is exceeded, the geocoder returns an error object
>   with the value kCLErrorNetwork to the associated completion handler.)
>   Here are some rules of thumb for using this class effectively:
>
> - Send at most one geocoding request for any one user action.
> - If the user performs multiple actions that involve geocoding the same    location, reuse the results from the initial geocoding request
>     instead of starting individual requests for each action.
> - When you want to update the user’s current location automatically       (such as when the user is moving), issue new geocoding requests only
>     when the user has moved a significant distance and after a reasonable 
>     amount of time has passed. For example, in a typical situation, you
>     should not send more than one geocoding request per minute.
> - Do not start a geocoding request at a time when the user will not see    the results immediately. For example, do not start a request if
>     your     application is inactive or in the background.

You can only submit one geocoding request at a time, and you're not supposed to submit more than ~1 per minute. Code like this would work:

```
let arrayOfAddresses = ["123 main street denver CO", "100 W. 23rd street, NY, NY", ]

var addressesToGeocode: [String]!
var geocoder = CLGeocoder()  //Configure the geocoder as needed.

///Call this function to geocode your entire array of addresses.
func geocodeArrayOfaddresses() {
  //Copy over the array of addresses.
  addressesToGeocode = arrayOfAddresses
  geocodeNextAddress()
}

func geocodeNextAddress() {
  guard !addressesToGeocode.isEmpty else {
    return
  }
  //Pull an address out of the array.
  let address = addressesToGeocode.removeLast()

  //Submit a geocoding request for this address.
  geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) {
    (placemarks, error) in
    //Once we're done with the completion block, submit another geocoding
    //request after a minute delay.
    defer {
      //Wait 60 seconds before geocoding the next address.
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(wallDeadline: .now() + 60.0) {
        self.geocodeNextAddress()
      }
    }
    if let error = error {
      print(error)
    }
    if let placemarks = placemarks,
      placemarks.count > 0 {
      if let location = placemarks.first?.location {
        print("The longitude: \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
        print("The latitude: \(location.coordinate.latitude)")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried adding `sleep(2)` at the end of the for loop, but it still only returns once

Comment: Using sleep is almost never a good idea, especially from the main thread. rmaddy included a link to suggestions on how to do multiple geocode requests in his answer. At a minimum, you'll need to refactor your code to submit a request and wait for it to complete before submitting the next one.

Comment: Using sleep(2) was the suggestion in that link of suggestions

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I showed you how to submit one request after another with a delay between. The docs say you're not supposed to submit more than one geocoding request per minute, so that's what my sample code does.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation for the `geocodeAddressString` method (highlighting mine):

> This method submits the specified location data to the geocoding server asynchronously and returns. Your completion handler block will be executed on the main thread. **After initiating a forward-geocoding request, do not attempt to initiate another forward- or reverse-geocoding request.**
>
> Geocoding requests are rate-limited for each app, so making too many requests in a short period of time may cause some of the requests to fail. When the maximum rate is exceeded, the geocoder passes an error object with the value network to your completion handler.

So basically you can't use a simple loop to make a whole bunch of concurrent requests. See [Strategy to perform many Geocode requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619134/strategy-to-perform-many-geocode-requests) for one possible solution.

Comment: I have tried adding `sleep(2)` at the end of the for loop, but it still only returns once

Answer (score -1):

To avoid this problem, I had declared the geocoder on the loop :

```
...
for shop in self.shopsList {
    let shopAddress = shop.address
    **let geocoder = CLGeocoder()**
    **geocoder**.geocodeAddressString(shopAddress, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
        if let error = error {
        print(error)
        return
        }...
```